# How to iterate over YAML doc in perl after storing it in a hashref

Tags: perl, hash

I have to process a YAML document:

```
sheet : filename.exe

book : bookname

characters :

   - amy : mother

   - mark : father

   - dave : son
```

Now I have the following code where I want to iterate and save the "character" in a hash to use later:

```
use YAML qw(LoadFile);
my $config = LoadFile('config.yaml');
my %charlist = ();
foreach my $key (keys %$config){
  next if ($key ne "character");
  foreach my $list (keys %{$config{$key}}){
    my $current_character = $config{$key}{$list};
    $charlist->{$list} = $current_character;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to store it into a hash like this:

```
{ amy => mother,
  mark => father,
  dave => son
}
```

I'm not able to go into the second foreach loop.  I'm not able to understand the issue.

Comment: Always use `use strict;` use warnings;`. It would have caught your proble,

Comment: One problem would seem to be confusion between the words "characters" and "character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;` (or equivalent). It would have found some problems.

---

Your question has nothing to do with YAML. It's about navigating the data structure produced by the YAML. So let's start by using the following to find out more about the data structure:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print(Dumper($config));
```

We get:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'sheet' => 'filename.exe',
          'book' => 'bookname',
          'characters' => [
                            {
                              'amy' => 'mother'
                            },
                            {
                              'mark' => 'father'
                            },
                            {
                              'dave' => 'son'
                            }
                          ]
        };
```

We only care about the `$config->{characters}`, which is a reference to an array (as shown by `[]`), so we're going to have something of the following form:

```
my %characters;
for (@{ $config->{characters} }) {
   ...
}
```

Each element of the array is a hash containing a a single character. We can use `%h = (%h, %extra);` to merge it in.

```
my %characters;
for my $character_container (@{ $config->{characters} }) {
   %characters = ( %characters, %$character_container);
}
```

Alternative:

```
my %characters;
for my $character_container (@{ $config->{characters} }) {
   @characters{ keys(%$character_container) } = values(%$character_container);
}
```

That's it!

---

Note that your file format is rather odd. It should be:

```
sheet : filename.exe

book : bookname

characters :

   amy : mother

   mark : father

   dave : son
```

This gives

```
$VAR1 = {
          'book' => 'bookname',
          'characters' => {
                            'mark' => 'father',
                            'dave' => 'son',
                            'amy' => 'mother'
                          },
          'sheet' => 'filename.exe'
        };
```

And the solution becomes

```
my $characters = $config->{characters};
```

Ok, maybe your question has something to do with YAML after all :)

---

@toolic's [endorses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61327928/589924) the use of

```
foreach my $key (keys %{ $config }) {
    next if ($key ne "characters");
    ...$config->{$key}...
}
```

But that's a particularly bad way of writing

```
if ( my $characters = $config->{$key} ) {
  ...$characters...
}
```

We specifically use hashes to be able to lookup elements by their key. Iterating over all of the elements to lookup one by key makes no sense. (I brought this to their attention, but they left the bad practice in place.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, the 'hyphen' in YAML under character doesn't imply anything?

Comment: It obviously does since it caused the data structure to be different. Compare the two dumps in my answer. Specifically, `-` denotes the elements of an array. But it doesn't make sense to use an array here.

Answer (score 1):

If you had `use strict;`, you would have seen several compile errors.

I used `Data::Dumper` to look at the structure returned by `LoadFile` to make it easier to dereference the structure.  The `characters` are stored as an array, not a hash.  You also tried to access `config` as a hash instead of a hashref.

Also, [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) is an excellent source for understanding references.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use YAML qw(LoadFile);
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1; 

my $config = LoadFile('config.yaml');

my %charlist;
foreach my $key (keys %{ $config }){
    next if ($key ne "characters");
    foreach my $list (@{ $config->{$key} }){
        %charlist = (%charlist, %{ $list });
    }
}

print Dumper(\%charlist);
```